# to train the neural network to simulate the interior and the arrangement of furniture

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

Is any dataset and codefor task to simulate the interior and the arrangement of furniture ?
For example like in nvidia post?
https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/archigan-generative-stack-apartment-building-design/
however, without modeling furniture arrangement